# Bash get n characters before a specified character

Tags: string, bash

This is the string:

```
Volume: 0:  120% 1:  128%
```

I want to get 3 characters before "%" character. So output must be like `120 128` for this example. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `grep`:

```
$ grep -Po '...(?=%)' file
120
128
```

Which is the same as:

```
grep -Po '.{3}(?=%)' file
```

or this if you want to make sure you get digits:

```
grep -Po '[0-9]{3}(?=%)' file
```

#### Explanation

The idea underlying is to print three characters before `%` is found. `(?=%)` indicates this and is called a "look-ahead".

With `-Po` we indicate grep that it can use Perl regular expressions (`-P`) and to just print the matches (`-o`).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you actually want everything between whitespace and a % (which is the same for this example), you could do:

```
awk '{print $NF}' RS=% ORS=' '
```